# How to create a new table from join 2 exists table

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I want to create a new table from joining 2 exists table.
these tables  has relation that id table 1 is FK from id table 2.

i already try this and it doesn't work :

```
CREATE TABLE joined2tables  
(SELECT detil_bet.*, detail_game.* 
FROM detil_bet 
      INNER JOIN detail_game 
              ON detil_bet.id_game = detail_game.id_game);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
SELECT something, somethingElse 
INTO YourNewTable 
FROM someTable 
JOIN someOtherTable ON someCondition
```

This will inherit the data types from the results.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the table first, and then insert rows. Look at your existing tables to find the correct columns, then do a `SELECT INTO`

For example, if you had the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
    EmployeeId int,
    Salary money,
    DateOfLastHokeyPokey datetime,
    PRIMARY KEY( EmployeeId )
);

CREATE TABLE Manager (
    EmployeeId int,
    ManagingDepartmentId int,
    DateCompletedManagementTraining datetime,
    PRIMARY KEY( EmployeeId )
);
```

You could create the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE SalaryManagerReport (
    EmployeeId int,
    ManagingDepartmentId int,
    Salary money,
    PRIMARY KEY( EmployeeId )
);
```

To populate this table, you could do this:

```
INSERT INTO SalaryManagerReport
SELECT e.EmployeeId, m.ManagingDepartmentId, e.Salary
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Manager m ON e.EmployeeId=m.EmployeeId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
* FROM
detil_bet, detail_game WHERE
detil_bet.id_game = detail_game.id_game
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already have the answer.But for a better clarity I will post this answer which is a combination of [scsimon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6167855/scsimon) and [Robert Columbia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6471538/robert-columbia) answer.

**Method 1:**

```
SELECT e.EmployeeId, m.ManagingDepartmentId, e.Salary
INTO SalaryManagerReport
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Manager m ON e.EmployeeId=m.EmployeeId;
```

The above query works fine when you run it once but if you try to execute it multiple times,it gives an error saying there's already an object with that name. So, you will have to delete the the table and run it once again.

**Method 2:**

```
INSERT INTO SalaryManagerReport
SELECT e.EmployeeId, m.ManagingDepartmentId, e.Salary
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Manager m ON e.EmployeeId=m.EmployeeId;
```

This works fine in all the cases as the table creation query is different from the insertion query.

So, In case you want to execute it multiple times go for the second answer or else the first one.